# How to write these Pandoc Haskell filters in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, pandoc

### Question

I need to convert these Pandoc Haskell filters to Python using [pandocfilters].

```haskell
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter separator
  where separator (Para [Span ("",[],[]) [Str "___separator___"]])
          = RawBlock (Format "html") "<div class=\"separator\">***</div>"
        separator x = x
```

```haskell
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskel

import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter separator
  where separator (Para [Span ("",[],[]) [Str "___separator___"]])
          = (Para [Span ("",[],[]) [Str "***"]])
        separator x = x
```

I expect it will be of the general form

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str

def separator(key, value, format, meta):
    """Need to write this."""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(separator)
```

Bonus if someone knows how to add "centered" formatting to the second filter for the docx format.

### Background

In LaTeX I have a `\separator{}` macro which makes three centered `***`. When processing this with Pandoc to html and docx, I use an alternate macro definition for `\separator{}` which just creates the text `___separator___`. I then replace `___separator___` with content that works correctly in the new format. I need to switch from Haskell to Python filters for cross system compatibility reasons.

### Example

#### Input file looks like

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\separator}{\_\_\_separator\_\_\_}

    First paragraph.

    \separator{}

    Second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

### Default pandoc html output with no filter

```html
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p><span>___separator___</span></p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
```

#### Required html output when filtered:

```html
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<div class="separator">***</div>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
```

The docx filter shoud ideally produce a centered paragraph with `***`.

Comment: Can you give a short example of the markdown which will trigger the filter?

Comment: @user5402 Thanks, I've updated the question with a clear example of the input and output I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't have TeX installed, so can you just show my what the json looks like, e.g. `pandoc input.text -o output.json`

Comment: Relevant node: `--- Found a Para with value: [{'t': 'Span', 'c': [['', [], []], [{'t': 'Str', 'c': '___separator___'}]]}]` So basically, `value[0]['c'][1][0]['c'] == '___separator___'` Additionally, any idea how to make the output a `div` with a class and not just another paragraph?

Comment: Basically. AFAIK, a pandoc filter can only generate pandoc elements, so it has no concept of a `div`. You could, however, generate a horizontal rule, and then post-process the generated HTML that replaces all `<hr>` tags with whatever you want. Also, see this SO question: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200605/is-pandoc-capable-of-injecting-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-any-elements) Also, if you found my answer useful you should at least upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para

def sep(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Para':
       sys.stderr.write("--- Found a Para with value: " + str(value) + "\n")
       if len(value) == 1:
           if value[0]['t'] == 'Str' and value[0]['c'] == '---separator---':
               return Para( [ Str("FOUND A SEPARATOR") ] )
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(sep)
```

When given this input markdown:

```
This is a paragraph.

---separator---

This is another paragraph.

---separator---
```

it will produce this output HTML via `pandoc --filter ... input.md -o output.html`:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>FOUND A SEPARATOR</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>FOUND A SEPARATOR</p>
```

It also prints to stderr the structure of the Para nodes so that you can see exactly what they look like.

Comment: This is working on your markdown example, but (after changing --- to ___) trying it on the LaTeX example, it doesn't work. The debug output you added looks very helpful though.

Comment: If you show me what the debugging output looks like I can fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

### For LaTeX to HTML:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para, RawBlock

def separator(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Para':
       if len(value) == 1:
           try:
               if value[0]['c'][1][0]['c'] == '___separator___':
                   return RawBlock('html', '<div class="separator">***</div>')
           except KeyError:
               return None
    return Nonepprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(separator)
```

### For LaTeX to docx:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para, RawBlock

def separator(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Para':
       if len(value) == 1:
           try:
               if value[0]['c'][1][0]['c'] == '___separator___':
                   return Para([Str('***')])

       except KeyError:
           return None
return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(separator)
```

Note that this doesn't center the `***` as I can't seem to work out how to inject that formatting.